# Calculate the area of individual pixels after clipping an image to a region of interest in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a defined area of interest, to which I have clipped the image I would like to use for analysis. However, I would like to exclude the partial pixels that result from clipping the image. The way I thought I would solve this is by adding the size of each pixel within the clipped area to the image as a band, so that the pixel area is stored in the same way as the spectral band values. It would then be easy to mask out the pixels that are smaller than the modal pixel size within the area of interest. How would I do this?

Here is some code with the clipping process and the area of interest:

```
//AOI
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([13.15, 56.75])

var pointBuff = point.buffer(100)

//Image collection
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")

var sampleImage = imgCol.filterBounds(pointBuff).first()

//Clipping image
var clippedImage = sampleImage.clip(pointBuff)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].

Comment: Was there something wrong with my question? I haven't posted questions on the site since 2021, but I had a period then when I was somewhat active.

Comment: While a raster in a geographic coordinate system has variable area pixels due to angular units, the concepts of a "partial pixel" and "modal pixel size" violate the principle of rasters modeling area with uniform-size objects. While you could model the rasters with vector objects (which is computationally expensive) or oversample the raster (ditto), the process of adding an "area" band isn't likely to scale well. While the login has existed for years,  your account has no badges and SE reports you to be a new user..

Comment: Ah, I just checked, and it looks like I've asked GEE questions on the Earth Science SE! I'm sorry for the confusion. The issue I'm trying to solve is that I have a boundary within which I have clipped imagery, but because I will be looking at NDVI or EVI, it's important that only pixels that are entirely within the boundary are included. When I export the individual pixel values for each image later, it's important that no pixels that are intersected by the edge of my boundary are included. Essentially, I only want to include "whole" pixels.

Comment: If you negative buffer the boundary by the square root of the pixel size, you won't get any false positive pixels (though  you may lose others, as false negatives). You could also oversample the pixels by thirds and look for overlap that way.

Answer (score 0):

Clipping that results in partial pixels sets the mask value to how much of the pixel was left. If you want to discard partial pixels completely, just set the mask of the clipped image such that any pixel with a mask < 1 is completely masked.

```
var result = clippedImage.mask(clippedImage.mask().eq(1))
```

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't working, but I tried it and there are still partial pixels that aren't masked? Please see this script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4457cc4e81507f4b1f511d43dc0494ab